# [Linux LEAP 15.1][mariadb 10.4.3][C API] The UTF8 characters are not handled as before (10.2.9)

Tags: mariadb, api

This C source code extract is expected to execute a query... but even if I change the name of the table from "Localités" to "Localites", the program no longer display the utf8 characters as the database could when I execute the same query in command line.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598955/linux-leap-15-1mysql-cliebt-1-4-3-can-not-run-mysql-query-since-upgrade)

The situation "before" gave those results that were expected:
[Expected situation](https://paste.opensuse.org/72894693)

I really don't know how tell the client (as the server respects the unicode) to display the datas as this program did since upgrade :{

Comment: Salut. You appear to have the "Erreur..." in both the problem area **and** the "expected" one. Could you post both your outputs (expected/working and the error situation) as **formatted text* here? Also, could you post the `C` code and other information from comments (i.e. logs &c) from the StackOverflow post here also? It's best to have **all** the information in one place! Then, put a link to this post in your post on StackOverflow to here so that there isn't duplication of effort. p.s. bienvenu sur le forum DBA.SE! :-)

Comment: @verace Greetings ^^ I show in the picture that with the "newer" version at this time (before upgrades to LEAP 15.1) that we can not have a mysql_query() running as expected. Once downgraded we could. I dug further and discovered it is a particular utf8 related issue. I don't know why the C API (connector C) doesn't want to communicate utf8 characters as it was communating until version 10.2.9... I'm at class room for now and I will post the requested elements tonite ^^